# Given $x,y\in\mathbb R$ is there a "formulaic" way to obtain a $q\in\mathbb Q$ with $a<q<b?$

Tags: real-analysis, computer-science, first-order-logic, real-numbers, decimal-expansion

Is there an assignment of reals $x,y$ to a rational number $q(x,y)$ for which

$$\forall_{\mathbb R} x.\forall_{\mathbb R}(x<y).\left(x<q(x,y)<y\right)\hspace{.2cm}?$$

For [computable reals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number#Formal_definition), using the definition, I can show existence of $F$ by averaging the upper and lower bounds for $a$ and $b$, respectively. In fact I can do it practically by truncating the first decimal where $a$ and $b$ differ and trail with a lot of zeroes and then a $1$.

Maybe the answer is no due to undecidability issues of $\le$ for $a,b$ in the first place?

Comment: Without any restrictions, such a function exists, yes. What kind of restrictions should there be on $q$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I'd like to know what it looks like or, if it can't be be constructed, what statements are responsible for it's existence.

Comment: With the axiom of choice, for example: for all $a<b$, $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is nonempty so $\prod_{a<b} (a,b) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is nonempty. An element of this set gives the function you want.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: k, I'm not sure about the indexing in $\Pi_{a<b}$, can you comment on this? More importantly, do we have a chance of getting $f$ this constructively, given reals which are set up classically?

Comment: It's a product indexed over the set $\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a < b \}$. Henning Makholm gave an example of a "constructive" $f$ in his answer.

Comment: [Continued fraction: Best rational within an interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_within_an_interval)

Comment: @StevenTaschuk: The section you directly linked to is for reals which have a computable decimal expansion. Is there more to it?

Comment: Decimal representations enter only into the example application there.  What is needed is the continued fraction representations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a definite arithmetic-looking formula you could do something like:

Let $n = 1+\left\lfloor \frac1{b-a} \right\rfloor$ -- then there will be at least one rational with denominator $n$ strictly between $a$ and $b$.

Now $\displaystyle\frac{1+\lfloor n a \rfloor}{n} $ will be the smallest such rational.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: You blow up the interval given by $a<b$ to a larger one given by $na<nb$ so that an integer $q'$ fits in, $na<q'<nb$. Then you map that $q'$ into a $q$ with $a<q<b$ in a way which preserves rationality. One last thing, can floor be found for any wild real $\frac{1}{b-a}$ specified by some formula?

Comment: @NikolajK: What about the floor function is not a "formula" to you?

Comment: Say I got a predicate $P$ which provably holds for one term $c\in \mathbb R$. Can I always ask for floor of $c$ and in this way obtain a number, e.g. $5$ or $9001$?

Comment: @NikolajK: Such as $P(x)\equiv (x=5\land\text{the Riemann Hypothesis is true})\lor(x=9001\land\text{the Riemann Hypothesis is false})$?

Comment: Okay, so if understand your question, you say that the value of a function that I want to evaluate at a number $c\in\{0,1\}$, for which $P(x)\equiv(x=0\land\text{Gödel sentence})\lor(x=1\land\neg\text{Gödel sentence})$ holds, can never be computed. So the answer to my later question is no.